# Displaying ImageDescription from a jpg photo with PHP

Tags: php, syntax, exif

I have a photo with a Norwegian character in the Image Description. This PHP code is not displaying the character properly.

```
    $exif = exif_read_data('1.jpg','IFD0',true);
    echo $exif["IFD0"]["ImageDescription"];
```

The character is written correctly as it I can see it in Windows and Adobe Bridge. Also when I upload the same file to this online viewer the Image Description displays correctly with the Norwegian character.

https://exifdata.com/exif.php

So I know it is possible, but they don't list their source.

Any help greatly received.

Links Below

My non-working file:
https://www.garryjones.se/testit/

The photo with the Norwegian character in Image Description https://www.garryjones.se/testit/1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php), there is a NOTE:

> If mbstring is enabled, exif will attempt to process the unicode and
> pick a charset as specified by exif.decode_unicode_motorola and
> exif.decode_unicode_intel. The exif extension will not attempt to
> figure out the encoding on its own, and it is up to the user to
> properly specify the encoding for which to use for decoding by setting
> one of these two ini directives prior to calling exif_read_data().

You only have to find out how to do the `ini` setting, but luckily someone added that info 15 years ago, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#73645

> When reading EXIF information from the 'WINXP' group, you may need to
> change used encoding from the default "ISO-8859-15" to "UTF-8". This
> can be done in php.ini or in your code:
>
> ````
>     ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');
>
>     $exif = exif_read_data('TEST.JPG', 0, true);
>     echo $exif['WINXP']['Title']; ?> ```
> ````